# Solving Ax = b where A is composed of diagonal blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations, block-matrices

I would like to solve the equation $Ax=b$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is of the form:
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
D_1 & D_2 &D_3 \\
D_2 & D_4 & D_5 \\
D_3 & D_5 & D_6
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $D_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are diagonal matrices for $i=1,\ldots,6$.

Any suggestions please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't $x\in \mathbb {R}^{3n}$?

Answer (score 1):

This system is equivalent to $n$ independent $3 \times 3$ systems, which can be solved in parallel.

Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}$, where each $x_i \in \mathbb R^n$.  Similarly let $b = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}$.

The $i$th $3 \times 3$ system is
\begin{align}
D_1^i x_1^i + D_2^i x_2^i + D_3^i x_3^i &= b_1^i \\
D_2^i x_1^i + D_4^i x_2^i + D_5^i x_3^i &= b_2^i \\
D_3^i x_1^i + D_5^i x_2^i + D_6^i x_3^i &= b_3^i.
\end{align}

(Here $x_1^i$ is the $i$th component of $x_1$, $D_1^i$ is the $i$th diagonal entry of $D_1$, etc.)